# Cloud Manager for Android

Tags: android, cloud-storage

I'm looking for an application that would let me access all my cloud accounts like Mega, Gdrive, Onedrive, Dropbox, box,idrive, etc.,

**Application Should**

- Free or Paid
- Support all file operations like(rename, delete, copy, move etc)
- Support for multiple accounts
- Storage Analysis
- Optional(Duplicate file remover, large file indicator)
- Secure & Safe

For Android 7+

Answer (score 1):

Do you prefer web services? If you have multiple different cloud storage, then I'd say MultCloud. Mover can be an alternative, but the supported connectors are not as many as MultCloud does.